# Pricing of a call option in one period binomial model

Tags: options, option-pricing, binomial, call

You are given a $5\%$ call option worth $\$2.66$. The strike price $k$ is $\$41.00$. $S(0)=40$, $Sd=35$ (i.e the lower price of the stock at $t=1$) find $Su$ (i.e the high price of the stock at $t=1$).

How would this be done? I know $Cu=Su-\$41$, $C(0)=\$2.66$ and I have something written in my notes that $c(0)= B/(1+r) +ΔS(0)$, but I'm not sure what $B$ is here. I assume to find $Su$ I need to first find $Cu$, but I'm not sure how to do this from the given information. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By no arbitrage, $S(0)=(Su q+Sd (1-q))/(1+r)$ and $C(0)=((Su-k)^+ q+(Sd-k)^+(1-q))/(1+r)$.
Simplifying and rearranging (and assuming $Su>k$),
$$\left[\begin{array}{c} 
S(0) \\
C(0)
\end{array} \right]=\frac{1}{1+r}\left[\begin{array}{cc} 
Su & Sd \\
(Su-k) & 0 
\end{array} \right]\left[\begin{array}{c} 
q\\
1-q
\end{array} \right] $$
Clearly, $q=C(0)(1+r)/(Su-k) $.  Substituting this back into the first equation,
 $$S(0)=\left(\frac{Su C(0)(1+r)}{Su-k}+Sd (1-\frac{C(0)(1+r)}{Su-k})\right)/(1+r)$$
After simplifying and solving for Su,
 $$Su=\frac{kS(0)(1+r)-kSd-C(0)Sd(1+r)}{S(0)(1+r)-C(0)(1+r)-Sd}$$